# I want to slice my big list into multiple lists on the basis of index numbers, Python

Tags: python

for example

```
def createList(r1, r2): 
    return [item for item in range(r1, r2+1)]
hundredList = createList(1, 100)    #this list would be simple = (1,2,3,4...99,100)

indexnums = (3,8,13,19,30,45,56,75,79,91) #this doesn't have a pattern it is random
```

I want to create a nested list which uses the first two index numbers to slice, then the second two index number to slice and so on. the resultant nested list would be:-

```
nestedList = ((1,2,3),(4,5,6,7,8),(9,10,11,12,13),.....
```

I know I have to use slicing here but I cannot figure out the loop which uses the first 2 index numbers as parameters for the slicing function and then second 2 index numbers and so on.

Comment: Your question isn't clear, what is happening with index numbers 3 & 8? Rather your output isn't clear, what is the significance of every 2 index numbers? Say for 3 & 8?

Comment: Why  this (2,3,4,5,6,7,8)?

Comment: I think I understand. You want to first take `3` and `8`, and slice your `hundredList` at those indecies to yield the first nested list. Then, do the same thing again, but this time slicing between index `8` and `13` to yield the next nested list, and so on. However, if your first slice starts at index `3`, which is the fourth element, and ends before index `8` (exclusive), which is the 9th element, wouldn't the nested list look like `[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`? Also, do you want tuples, or lists?

Comment: @PaulM. I thought so too, but his expected Output doesn't seem to indicate that.

Comment: You are correct paul i should have checked my expected output, now I have corrected it, I will link my email for the replies from stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

This is very straightforward

Code:

```
hundredList = list(range(1, 101))
indexnums = (3,8,13,19,30,45,56,75,79,91)
result = []
prv_n = 0
for n in indexnums:
    result.append(tuple(list(hundredList[prv_n:n])))
    prv_n = n
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6, 7, 8), (9, 10, 11, 12, 13), (14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19), (20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30), (31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45), (46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56), (57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75), (76, 77, 78, 79), (80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91)]
```

Comment: Wow this is really good! thanks a lot! I need to practice my logic more!